# What should the scheduler be for delay and debounce in Combine? (Xcode 11 beta 1 only)

Tags: swift, xcode, combine

**This issue would ideally be deleted because it is related to obsolete beta version of Xcode only.**

[WWDC Video 721 Combine in Practice][1] seems to indicate that RunLoop.main should be a valid scheduler to use in Combine with `delay` or `debounce` but I'm seeing compile errors with Xcode claiming that RunLoop doesn't conform to scheduler. Am I doing something wrong or is this just an issue with the first beta of Xcode.

```
ContentView.swift:95:77: error: argument type 'RunLoop' does not conform to expected type 'Scheduler'
        return delayPublisher.debounce(for: .seconds(5), scheduler: RunLoop.main).eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

I've raised FB6160439.

[1]: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/721/ (slides 79, 80, 211).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it only applies to the very first beta version of Xcode 12 (beta 1) and it is no longer of any relevance to anyone. It was my question if that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Foundation Combine integrations weren't available in the first beta build. They're available in the second beta (6/17/19), so you just need to update your Xcode 11 beta.

Comment: Yeah, I spotted it come in last night. I’ve got it compiling but not working now. Might try to delete the question in a week or so rather than leave beta 1 clutter around. Apologies if your points also disappear then.